# Is it possible to run Java web application using Nginx server only without tomcat server ?

Tags: nginx, tomcat, java, web

I am having Java web application (with RESTful webservices). Currently it is running on tomcat server.
Is it possible to run Java web application using Nginx server only without tomcat server ?? 
Please suggest if you have any idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for alternatives for Apache Tomcat, you got [`Glassfish`](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/) or [`Wildfly`](http://www.wildfly.org/) to serve as an application server.

If you're looking for alternatives against running an application server, which I don't recommend, there are few options:

1. implement FastCGI, WSGI, or SCGI server on top of your Java application. I can't find a mature enough implementations of any of them, YMMV; but there's [JWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/JWSGI.html) as WSGI implementation, though still not a standard.
2. build a HTTP server in java on top of your app, then proxy clients' requests through nginx.
3. implement CGI on top of your Java app. It's dirty, it's slow, it's dangerous, but it works. I don't recommend this though, there are better alternatives.